# Proxmox migration succeeds but no image copied

Tags: virtual-machine

I have a Proxmox 4.X cluster, and I am trying to migrate VM's between nodes. When I attempt to migrate a VM, I get a log saying it succeeded. In addition, the VM appears under that node. However, when I check the image folder of that node, no image appears. I have made all storages checked as shared. Why would this be happening, and what are some suggestions on how to fix it?

Here is my cluster status:

[image: image: cluster status]

Source node:

[image: image: node 1 description]

Destination node:

[image: node 2 description]

Answer (score -1):

You need a **real shared** common storage to do this like nfs, DRBD, GlusterFS, CephFS... If you use local storage without replication, that will not work. (you'll migrate the VM without disks)